# Sugerencia: Etiqueta "Primeros pasos"

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas

Estoy planteando una serie de preguntas sobre kivy, un framework para hacer app móviles usando python, que creo que son muy básicas, aunque a mi me ayudan bastante porque estoy empezando de cero.

Todas las preguntas que he planteado sobre kivy guardan un patrón que es que tratan de cosas básicas al realizar una GUI para una App siendo propias de alguien que está empezando.

Hecho en falta una etiqueta que refleje el hecho de que son preguntas que uno se plantea durante el inicio de la curva de aprendizaje.

Creo que podríamos tener una etiqueta que recoja ese esfuerzo para cualquier herramienta o lenguaje y pueda presentar una colección de preguntas que ayudan a despegar. Una etiqueta así podría presentarnos la información en un formato como de curso de inicio para cualquier herramienta que se trate.

Así por ejemplo en mi caso, hacer GUI para App in Kivy, la una etiqueta "Primeros pasos" recogería las preguntas esenciales sobre kivy que alguien se puede hacer cuando se está iniciando. De tal manera que a otra persona que se iniciase en hacer GUIs en Kivy podría localizar más fácilmente las preguntas naturales que surgen al empezar con ello.

Muchas gracias por vuestra atención.

Answer (score 1):

La idea como tal en mi opinion no es mala, salvo por como funciona el sitio, quiero decir es un lugar de preguntas y respuestas.

Pues si usted cree que son preguntas basicas que usted no sabe las puede formular sin mas en SOes, y esperar una respuesta, de esta manera quedaran para otros que se formulen la misma prenguta ya sea usando el buscador del sitio o de cualquier motor de busqueda como google.

Por otro lado usted puede formular una pregunta y una respuesta y publicarlas al mismo tiempo, (no es muy correcto abusar de esto en mi opinion) pero puede hacerlo eso si intente que sea una pregunta clara sobre un tema especifico bien redactada mirar: [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y publicar al mismo tiempo la respuesta centrandose solo en la pregunta no se trata de hacer un tutorial de iniciacion.

Con lo que esto me lleva a lo siguiente usted puede editar las etiquetas en este caso [kivy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy), y añadir enlaces a la documentacion oficial muchas tecnologias tienen en su pagina web enlaces a tutoriales de como empezar ect, una vez que se añaden al tag , esta informacion y es aceptada usted o cualquiera puede acceder al tag y pulsar en la parte de [más información…](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/kivy/info)

y ver mas detalles sobre el tag o la tecnologia, dentro de la misma puede contener enlaces a tutoriales basicos ect.