# Incluyamos dentro del Tour alguna información acerca de las etiquetas para promocionar su uso

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, centro-de-ayuda, recorrido

Después de esta pregunta:

[Sugerencia: Etiqueta "Primeros pasos"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1765/sugerencia-etiqueta-primeros-pasos/)

Me preguntaba y creo que no, que en ningun sitio se invita a los nuevos usuarios a mirar la etiqueta "tag" sobre la que esta interesado y mucho menos se le invita a mirar la pararte de mas informacion.

No es que piense que sea algo trivial, pero si es verdad bajo mi punto de vista, que se a puesto en ello un esfuerzo en conjunto, tanto en crear el tag, que la plataforma soporte esta caracteristica, que proporciona un resumen de la tecnologia de facil acceso, asi como cosas de utilidad como ejemplos minimos, versiones actuales ect, (claro que varia de una etiqueta a otra).

Pues eso, creo que seria bueno dar mas visibilidad a esta parte de lo plataforma, para que mas usuarios la conozcan y se beneficien de ella, y por otro lado, cuantos mas usuarios conozcan esta parte, quizas la calidad en cuanto a informacion dentro del los tag pueda mejorarse, actualizarse y ampliarse de una manera mas constante.

Tambien para los usuarios que quieren colaborar con el sitio, pero no tiene tiempo (o suerte) de encontrar una pregunta a la que contestar, o no tener los conocimientos para ello o cualquier cosa, pero aun asi quiere ayudar a mejorar el sitio, podrian emplear ese tiempo en mejorar los tag, y de paso se sacan unos puntillos, que podrian venir bien para entrar en el chat, y poder acceder a otras caracteristicas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> creo que no, que en ningun sitio se invita a los nuevos usuarios a mirar la etiqueta

Ya se encuentra dentro del [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

[image: Las etiquetas permiten encontrar preguntas interesantes fácilmente]

Y se ofrece el enlace a la [lista de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags).

Además, en [Nuestro Modelo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

> #### Navegación por etiqueta
>
> Cada pregunta hecha en nuestro sitio es etiquetada de acuerdo a los
>   temas que la describen. Cada una de estas etiquetas tiene su propia
>   página wiki y una lista de preguntas en dicha etiqueta. Para encontrar
>   preguntas sobre un tema específico, [visita la página de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags)
>   y navega a través de las etiquetas populares o busca una etiqueta
>   específica.
>
> Clicando una etiqueta – desde cualquier lugar del sitio, ya sea desde
>   la página de la etiqueta o desde la etiqueta debajo de una pregunta –
>   te mostrara una lista de todas las preguntas con esa etiqueta y una
>   wiki de etiqueta que describe de que trata la etiqueta en sí y para
>   que se usa en este sitio. Allí podrás ordenar las preguntas por
>   diferentes criterios como preguntas sin respuesta, más votadas, las
>   preguntas más nuevas y otras opciones.

... y sigue hablando de etiquetas.

---

> mucho menos se le invita a mirar la pararte de mas informacion

Creo que esto no es la información central del sitio. Las preguntas y respuestas son lo más importante. A un usuario nuevo, lo primero que creo que conviene recomendarle es que revise otras publicaciones y que intente realizar preguntas de la mejor forma posible, una vez familiarizado con el formato de otras buenas preguntas.

No obstante, en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (el artículo de la ayuda más enlazado en todo el sitio), se menciona:

> #### Incluye todas las etiquetas relevantes
>
> Intenta incluir una etiqueta para el lenguaje, librería y otros APIs
>   específicos relacionados a tu pregunta. Si inicias tecleando en el
>   campo de etiquetas, el sistema te sugerirá etiquetas que coincidan con
>   lo que hayas tecleado -
>   **¡asegúrate y lee la descripción brindadas a ellas para cerciorar que ellas son relevantes a la pregunta que estás formulando!**
>   Mira también:
>   [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debería utilizarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Y en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debería utilizarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) se describe con mucho más detalle. Por ejemplo, explica cuándo un usuario debería re-etiquetar una pregunta:

> #### Re-etiquetando
>
> Como parte del [proceso de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), los usuarios pueden sugerir
>   ediciones o directamente editar las etiquetas de una pregunta si ellos
>   creen que cierta etiqueta es inapropiada o que es necesario agregar
>   una si esta falta.
>
> Debes re-etiquetar preguntas cuando:
>
> - Estás agregando de esta manera información valiosa a la pregunta
> - Estás sustituyendo etiquetas obscuras o difíciles de entender con etiquetas conocidas y populares que son apropiadas para la pregunta.

---

> cuantos mas usuarios conozcan esta parte, quizas la calidad en cuanto a informacion dentro del los tag pueda mejorarse, actualizarse y ampliarse de una manera mas constante.

Para fomentar la correcta utilización de etiquetas y la actualización de las wikis, están las medallas:

- [Organizador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer): Primer reetiquetado.
- [Creador de sinónimos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer): Aprobar un sinónimo de etiqueta por primera vez.
- [Editor de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor): Primera edición de wiki de etiqueta.
- [Asistente de investigación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant):  Editar 50 wikis de etiqueta
- [Taxónomo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist): Crear una etiqueta utilizada por 50 preguntas

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribir esto, yo mire lo que dices o casi todo antes de publicar, pero donde dice **Haz click en cualquier etiqueta...* sobre todo o en cual quier parte, creo que se pasa de puntillas sobre la informacion que contine dentro las mismas y que se pueden editar ect. y si esto aparece esta algo oculto me refiero que no se le explica de una forma mas amplia y sencilla desde el tour, me refiero a que tienes que visitar muchos link o saber de las medallas ect, para quizas entender que se pueden editar, cosa que con el tiempo se conoce o "no", la parte mas clara creo..

Comment: ...es en el link de tagging -> Re-etiquetando, pues ese parrafo pienso que seria bueno añadirlo en el tour en donde se habla de las etiquetas con un link por si se quiere profundizar, me refiero a ese parrafo por ejemplo dentro de la captura de imagen que pusistes, no es muy grande y creo que quedaria bien. Saludos

Comment: P.D: pero si gracias a tu respuesta puedo ver que existe informacion para conocer esta caracteristica aunque como dije creo que esta un poco oculta para los nuevo o quizas esa era la intencion.Saludos

Comment: **este parrafo** `Re-etiquetando`

Como parte del proceso de edición, los usuarios puede sugerir ediciones o directamente editar las etiquetas de una pregunta si ellos creen que cierta etiqueta es inapropiada o que es necesario agregar una si esta falta.

Comment: y poder ampliar, corregir, o actuatizar  la informacion que la etiqueta contiene. o algo asi. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel creo que en parte sí es intencional que no se dé tanta información sobre editar etiquetas, ya que lo debería sugerir un usuario que ya esté experimentado en el sitio... En cuanto a lo de re-etiquetado, lo pasé por alto, pero sentite en total libertad de editar mi respuesta si crees que puede agregar información valiosa.

Comment: *...sentite en total libertad de editar...* mejor no pues quizas no lo ponga en el sitio menos oportuno ademas esta en los comentarios y usted deja el link donde aparece, aun asi gracias por la invitacion, por otro lado ahora puedo entender mejor quizas el porque esto es asi. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Agregado ;-)