# Reubicar las instrucciones sobre la edición de los wikis de etiqueta

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, wiki-de-etiqueta

Las instrucciones sobre el contenido de los wikis de etiqueta se encuentran en el artículo sobre los privilegios de "Usuario de Confianza". Me parece que deberían dársele mayor difusión y colocar en un mejor lugar.

Mi sugerencia es que se incluyan ya sea en ¿Qué son las etiquetas y  cómo se usan? o bien en "Privilegio creación de etiquetas"

Lo anterior es relevante porque se sugiere que las etiquetas tengan las instrucciones de uso de la etiqueta así como el sentido que tiene la misma en el sitio en particular, sin embargo, tanto en SOes como en otros sitios de Stack Exchange el contenido wiki de muchas etiquetas carece de esta información.

---

Generalidades

- [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo se usan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Específicos

- [Privilegio creación de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- [Privilegio de aprobación de edición de wiki de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)
- [Privilegio de sugerencia de sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
- [Privilegio usuario de confianza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (Edición de resumen/wiki de etiquetas)

De https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1770/65

> Para fomentar la correcta utilización de etiquetas y la actualización
>   de las wikis, están las medallas:
>
> - [Organizador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer): Primer reetiquetado.
> - [Creador de sinónimos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer): Aprobar un sinónimo de etiqueta por primera vez.
> - [Editor de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor): Primera edición de wiki de etiqueta.
> - [Asistente de investigación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant):  Editar 50 wikis de etiqueta
> - [Taxónomo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist): Crear una etiqueta utilizada por 50 preguntas

---

Otros temas relacionados con etiquetas que no están discutidos aún en SOes

- Quemado (burnination) de etiquetas
- Incluir en la lista negra
- Eliminación de etiquetas

---

Publicación en Meta Stack Exchange

- [Tag Wiki best practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69584/289691)

Comment: Aun siendo diferente me da la sensacion, de que podria estar relaciona con esta pregunta que hice anteriormente -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1767/incluir-dentro-del-tour-alguna-informacion-acerca-de-los-tag-promocionar-esta no digo que sea un duplicado, pero quizas se complementen. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo en que están relacionadas y en que se complementan. Esta va más a que la ubicación del "contenido canónico" cambie, mientras que la otra habla de una forma de promocionar las etiquetas y su correcto uso, específicamente en el recorrido (tour).